# Avoiding django TemplateSyntaxError if {% block %} is in an if/else/endif?

Tags: django, django-templates

If I put a {% block xxx %} twice in a template, I understand the error.  But is there a way get django to ignore this error:

```
{% if foo %}
   complex stuff...
   {% block content %}
   complex stuff...
{% else %}
   complex stuff...
   {% block content %}
   complex stuff...
{% endif %}
```

It would make my code quite a bit cleaner.  Currently with Django 1.5 I get **'TemplateSyntaxError 'block' tag with name 'content' appears more than once"**.  Of course only one of those blocks can ever be triggered in the if/else.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `{% include "example.html" %}`,

which then itself contains the `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`